# No closing batch program

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I am trying to make a program in the windows bath shell that can not be closed or ignored (click close 'x' button, it does not close, and you can not click it off screen, could somebody give me the batch coding so I could do this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done.  Command Prompt is a MS program which is made to behave a certain way - you can't change its behavior beyond giving it commands to run.

Your best option is to create a WPF or WinForms application to do the job.

Comment: yes - it's the same as "I wish windows to continue running, when I remove power"